# Jquery cannot invoke a click, but can manually do it with a mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using D3 to create a map that holds some text objects scattered around. Each of the text objects has an ID attribute appended to it and some words for its value. Here is some sample code to understand what I am creating:

```
g.selectAll("text")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return "cows_name";})
    .text( function(d) { return "cows"; })
    .on("click", function(d) {
        alert("### we are in here" with $(this).attr("id"));
    })
```

When I manually click the "cows" text boject in my browser (Firefox 45), the alert event is called, and I am able to conclude that the id attribute retuns back "cows_name".

However, when I try to invoke this JQuery code in either Selenium or Scratchpad:

```
var toClick = $("#cows_name")
toClick.click();
```

Nothing happens at all. Is there something I am missing in understaning what is the correct way to "click" D3 objects that are generated using my above script?

Comment: You do `selectAll("text")`, could it be that more than on element have the id `cows_name` and thus it is ambigious?

Comment: click() is a method that exists on HTML elements, not on SVG elements.

Comment: Can you console log $(this) in the alert place to see that it is returning the cow_name element

Comment: @Paul you are correct about the possible ambiguity, however, my data collections only has 1 entry. Sorry, I should have been more specific.

Comment: @RobertLongson what is the correct way to do it on SVG elements?

Comment: @NagaSaiA when I console.log the element during  a manual browser click, it does indeed return values back that I expect, like functiosn that can be called on it, a constructor, etc

Comment: @NagaSaiA in comaprison to a href link on the page, one key difference I found is that the cows_name object has the selector attribute blank, whereas the href button has the actual value with a hashtag infront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's change your `toClick` to:

```
var toClick = $("#cow_name")[0];
```

This selects the actual DOM element. After changing your `toClick`, I found this cool function to "simulate" click events:

```
function fakeClick(target) {
    var event = new Event('click');
    target.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

And then, you call it:

```
fakeClick(toClick);
```

Here is the fiddle, using SVG elements: https://jsfiddle.net/ap1m1L0q/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
var toClick = $("#cows_name");
toClick.trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: .trigger seems to do nothing alike click. I console.log() the element when I manually click it, and it does have the trigger method within it however.

Comment: take a look at the updated comments ibelow the question, as the selector for that object seems to be empty. not sure if that has any issue with this or not